# iPad device UIToolbar bug which doesn't exist on simulator

Tags: ipad, ios-simulator, uitoolbar

When running the a universal app in the iPad simulator, the UIWebview shown below works great:

[image: iPad simulator]

However when I run it on an iPad, the UI looks as follows:

[image: iPad device]

This UIToolbar issue previously was an issue on both the device and simulator, but after I made some changes now only exists on the device...any ideas?

Comment: Check the autoresizingMask of the ToolBar. Did you consider to use a navigation controller instead of a toolBar?

Comment: I considered the navigation controller, but it wouldn't work as well for my app. I've also not touched the autoresizeingMask - and surely if that was the issue, it would show in the simulator too?